# Wiped all data. Way to create partitions post installation

Tags: partitioning

I installed Ubuntu using "Erase Disk" option unfortunately and that wiped all data and created one large partition.

Is there a way I can create more partitions now? I now only have one large disk and no other partitions. Is there a way to create partitions without reinstalling the Ubuntu?

Thanks!

Comment: You run gparted from a live USB and resize and make partitions

Comment: Thanks for answering! Can you please walk me through it? I am a complete newbie to Ubuntu/Linux.

Comment: Just install GParted(if not present) and open it. You'll get to know yourself.

Comment: @Kulfy cant do that from an I stalled system,  have to resize root from a live usb. @ Pankaj Vig see https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual

Comment: @Panther I forgot to mention that I was adding to your comment.

Comment: Did you figure it out yet? Yes it is possible to do that but there is always a risk of data loss/boot failure when using this method. Much safer to create partitions then do a fresh install.

Comment: Thanks everyone for trying to help me out. I agree @beertempest I will do a fresh install instead when I am able to. It's not worth the risk. Thanks again everyone. :-)